# Required Field Validator not working properly in gridview

Tags: c#, requiredfieldvalidator

Required Field Validator not working properly in gridview

I work in ASP.NET c# and MySQL database.

I need to make the required field of this **DropDownList** on **FooterTemplate**, but Required Field Validator not working.

Why ?

My code:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnInsert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" ImageUrl="/images/icon_2.gif"
        ToolTip="Add" OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm?');" />
</FooterTemplate>


<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtIDDTES" runat="server" CssClass="ddl_Class_new">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rtxtIDDTES" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtIDDTES"
        ErrorMessage="***" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Validation1"
        SetFocusOnError="true" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</FooterTemplate>


<asp:ValidationSummary ID="Validation1" ValidationGroup="Validation1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" />
```

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please remove ValidationGroup="Validation1" and see if it is working?

Comment: @M005 thank you, not working-

Comment: Can you try to add initial value like this <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rtxtIDDTES" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtIDDTES"
        ErrorMessage="***" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Validation1" 
        SetFocusOnError="true" EnableClientScript="true" InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: @M005 nothing, not working the value null is validate

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummaryTop" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />

...

<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtIDDTES" runat="server" CssClass="ddl_Class_new">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rtxtIDDTES" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtIDDTES"
        ErrorMessage="***" Text="*" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</FooterTemplate>
```